# Web Server File Uploading and Management

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, file, file-upload

I have a web server that hosts my website as well as content for my iPhone app (audio, plists, images, etc.) I am building an app for my mac that will take the audio files that I drag to it, analyze them, create a plist with the ID3 tag info and then upload the plist, the audio files, and the album art to my web server. This will cut the amount of time it takes to  update content(which I do weekly) drastically. I wanted to be able to view(and possibly edit) those files on my web server from a second view in my application. I have done many google searches and still don't know where to start. I could use a pointer in the right direction. When the project is complete I plan to upload it to github for others to use.  I figured the best place to start would be with the web server file viewer and file manager...any help would be awesome!

Cheers!